# Migrated website to new host, then updated new website. Now I want to move all new posts from old server to new one in WP

Tags: wordpress, migration

I have 2 websites, let's say aaa.com and bbb.com, both using WordPress as their CMS.  bbb.com is a rebranding of aaa.com.  So I created a duplicate of aaa.com using the duplicator plugin, put it on bbb.com, and rewrote the theme (under a new name).  Meanwhile, aaa.com is still being used and updated with new posts.  So how do I take the new posts and such from aaa.com and move them to bbb.com without screwing everything up?

Comment: If you just need new posts from aaa.com, just go to Tools > Export and choose the post type, and set a date range to export. Then on bbb.com go to Tools > Import and import that file.

Comment: Mostly worked.  I had to manually re-add all the featured images for the posts, but there was only about 10, so it wasn't a huge deal.  Thank you!